# Excel Macro keeps creating empty new components when clicked on the existing one to run

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run an Excel Marco by clicking on some buttons in it. However, each time I click on one of the buttons, in the associated VB Script, a new component is created automatically.

I want to run this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim B1 As Workbook
Dim B2 As Workbook
Dim S1 As Worksheet
Dim S2 As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ct As Integer

Dim ticket As Range
Dim tcnumber As Range
Dim ticketcol As Integer
Dim tcnumbercol As Integer
Dim tickethist As Range
Dim tickethistcol As Integer
Dim ticketnum As String
Dim langpath As String

langpath = [J2]
If IsEmpty([D3]) = True Then
    MsgBox ("Please select an Issue # to close.")
Else
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    Set B1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set S1 = B1.Sheets("JIRA")
    If Right(S1.Cells(2, "J"), 1) = "\" Then
        Set B2 = Workbooks.Open(langpath & [A3] & "\" & [A3] & ".xlsx")
    Else
        Set B2 = Workbooks.Open(langpath & "\" & [A3] & "\" & [A3] & ".xlsx")
    End If

    Set S2 = B2.Sheets("test_cases")

    Set ticket = S2.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Tickets", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ticketcol = ticket.Column

    Set tcnumber = S2.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="TC#", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    tcnumbercol = tcnumber.Column

    Set tickethist = S2.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Ticket History", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    tickethistcol = tickethist.Column

    ticketnum = [D3]

    k = S2.Cells(Rows.count, tcnumbercol).End(xlUp).Row

    ct = 0

    For i = 2 To k

        If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum)) > 0 Then
            ct = ct + 1
            If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum & ",")) > 0 Then 'if ticket is first or middle position
                If IsEmpty(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value) = True Then 'ticket history is empty
                    S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum & ","), "")
                    S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = UCase(ticketnum)
                Else 'if ticket history already contains ticket
                    If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum)) > 0 Then  'do nothing
                        S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum & ","), "")
                    Else 'ticket history is not empty, but doesnt contain the ticket
                        S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum & ","), "")
                        S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value & ", " & UCase(ticketnum)
                    End If
                End If

            Else 'if ticket is alone or last position
                If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), ", " & UCase(ticketnum)) > 0 Then 'if ticket is last position
                    If IsEmpty(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value) = True Then 'ticket history is empty
                        S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), ", " & UCase(ticketnum), "")
                        S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = UCase(ticketnum)
                    Else 'if ticket history already contains ticket
                        If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum)) > 0 Then 'do nothing
                            S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), ", " & UCase(ticketnum), "")
                        Else 'ticket history is not empty
                            S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), ", " & UCase(ticketnum), "")
                            S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value & ", " & UCase(ticketnum)
                        End If
                    End If

                Else 'if ticket is alone
                    If IsEmpty(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value) = True Then 'ticket history is empty
                        S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum), "")
                        S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = UCase(ticketnum)
                    Else 'if ticket history already contains ticket
                        If InStr(1, UCase(S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum)) > 0 Then 'do nothing
                            S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum), "")
                        Else 'ticket history is not empty
                            S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value = Replace(UCase(S2.Cells(i, ticketcol).Value), UCase(ticketnum), "")
                            S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value = S2.Cells(i, tickethistcol).Value & ", " & UCase(ticketnum)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
        End If

        Next i

        If S1.Range("J4").Value = "Yes" Then
            B2.Close (True)
        Else
        End If

        MsgBox ("JIRA issue moved to ticket history for all TCs. (" & ct & " TCs were affected.)")

    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrMsg:
    MsgBox ("Please check domain and path are correct. If they are, your spreadsheet might already be open and unsaved. Please re-save spreadsheet and try again."), , "File error"
End Sub
```

But what I get is this new component at the end of the script:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

End Sub
```

I tried copying CommandButton22 code into CommandButton5 so that it gets executed, but to no avail, because when I click on the associated button another new component gets created.

If I try to run the VB script by the run button in the code (and not in the design mode) I get this error though:

```
Compile error:

Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found
```

I have also tried deleting all the *.exd files but still no change in the outcome.

I'm using Microsoft Office 2010 on Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1.

Does anybody know how I can make Excel stick with the existing components and not creating or looking for new ones?

Comment: It's difficult from your question to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: It would help to post the rest of the code you're running from the button.

Comment: The code is running safe and sound on some other machines, so I don't think there's anything wrong with the code. But thanks anyways.

Comment: "I don't think there's anything wrong with the code" - "Wrong" is a relative term: just because it works for other people doesn't mean it's robust.

Comment: Sorry for misreading your comment. I edited the question to paste the whole code for the component. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's something wrong with maintaining object references in your program, or you're doing something wrong in your object creation or maintenance.

Each button object has a unique name. Ie there is a single button in your project called Button5, and nothing but your manual or code edits should be able to change that. So if you have a button called Button7, and clicking it causes a new command called Button9_Click() to appear, that is a big problem. There are a few possible causes: you are changing the name of the button manually or somewhere in your code, you are adding a new button which will not come with the other button's functions built-in, or Excel is dropping the previous reference to the button and referring to it with a new name (in this case uninstall and reinstall Excel).

PS If you are coding purely within Excel, you are not using VB.Net. That is a separate language with more robust features that is usually coded in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although the situation is exactly what you called a big problem! The script is not written by me, nor am I the only user of it. A couple of colleagues are running it fine with no problem, and only some of us are facing this issue. That's why we don't think anything is wrong with the code itself. I suspect some configuration issue with excel must have caused this.

Comment: If that is the case, I'm fairly certain one of my listed causes is the root of the problem. If you are sure it is not one of the first two, you should try reinstalling Excel.

Comment: In response to your edit, I agree. Please mark correct if reinstalling fixes the issue. On the other hand, it may be a permissions issue. Do your colleagues have Admin rights or write access while you do not? That would explain why it won't let you modify the original buttons.

Comment: I uninstalled the Office and did a fresh install, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. Best of luck